# Unterstanding the templates and the code with Eigen Library

Tags: c++, eigen

I've got this Code in school:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
template<<typename Scalar>
void Typedemo(unsigend int dim)
{
using dynMat_t =
Eigen::Matrix<Scalar,Eigen::Dynamic,Eigen::Dynamic>; 
using dynColVec_t= Eigen::Matrix<Scalar,Eigen::Dynamic,1>; 
using dynRowVec_t = Eigen::Matrix<Scalar,1,Eigen::Dynamic>; 
using index_t = typename dynMat_t::Index;
using entry_t = typename dynMat_t::Scalar;

dynColVec_t colvec(dim);
dynRowVec_t rowvec(dim); 

for (index_t i=0; i< colvec.size(); ++i) colvec(i) = (Scalar)i; 
for (index_t i=0; i< rowvec.size(); ++i) rowvec(i) = (Scalar)1/(i+1);
dynMat_t vecprod = colvec*rowvec;
const int nrows = vecprod.rows();
const int ncols = vecprod.cols(); 
}
```

I thought `Scalar` is the name of the template type (that might be instantiated as double or int) and `dynMat_t` is a Matrixtype like MatrixX"Scalar". Now i struggle with the meaning of `dynMat_t::Scalar`, is this the description of the value_type of the matrix/vector entries and why do you need the type `entry_t`?

I can't see the point of this code.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Scalar looks like whatever type that you need to see, it's a template.. Most likely to be matrix but I'm confused what your asking

Comment: Could it be the case the `Eigen::Matrix` has typenames `Index` and `Scalar`? I am not sure not how `Eigen::Matrix` looks like, so you could look there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, `Scalar` is a template parameter that specifies the scalar field (can be either a standard type or user defined type), see the [official Eigen documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html) and the line 97 of the source code [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/PlainObjectBase_8h_source.html), where

```
typedef typename internal::traits<Derived>::Scalar Scalar;
```

The `entry_t` is just a type alias, in this case same as `Scalar`, so I guess it's used just for uniformity of notation.

PS: you have a typo in your code, `template<<typename Scalar> void Typedemo(unsigend int dim)` should be `template<typename Scalar> void Typedemo(unsigend int dim)`.